# Retrieve JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to retrieve a JSON from a url.  So far I have

```
<script>
var co2;
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("0");
    $.getJSON(url,function(result){
        var jsonObject = result;
        alert(result);
        alert(result.Cumulative_CO2);
        co2 = result.Cumulative_CO2;
    });
}); 
</script>
```

the URL returns `[{"Cumulative_CO2":"406465.968076","Year":"2013","Month":"3","Day":"29"}]`

what I would like to do is take Cumulative_CO2 and store it in a var, but the `alert(result)` returns `[object Object]` and `alert(result.Cumulative_CO2)` returns `undefined`.   Am I doing something wrong retrieving the json?  I am brand new to this and cant figure out what to do next.

Comment: Give `result[0].Cumulative_CO2` a shot. It's returning an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `result[0].Cumulative_CO2`.  The result is wrapped in an array, so access the first item and then get the property from that object.

Answer (score 3):

The result is an array of json objects, in this case you need to get the first item in the array and then get the value of property `Cumulative_CO2`

```
alert(result[0].Cumulative_CO2);
```

Also: Need to consider the possibility of the case where the array might return more than one item.